# jQuery .add method seemingly not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if anyone can explain this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var popup = $('<div id="popup"><div class="popup-content"></div></div>');
        var popupContent = popup.children('div');
        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');

        console.log(popup);
        console.log(popupContent);
        console.log(overlay);
        console.log(overlay.add(popup).appendTo('body'));
    });
```

I've added some debugging in there in case you want to test it.

I don't understand why only the overlay gets appended when appendTo() is being called on a jQuery object containing two elements?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 37):

`.add()` doesn't modify the existing object, it returns a **new** object with the values in it.  So you aren't appending the object you think you are.

This portion of code does **NOT** modify the overlay object: `overlay.add(popup)`  Rather, it creates a new object, but since there is no reference to that new object, it is immediately lost--there is no way you can use it.  The overlay object itself is unchanged.

You should do something like this instead:

```
overlay = overlay.add(popup);
overlay.appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it has something to do with the overlay jQuery object having not been added to the DOM yet.  The jquery doc on .add says:

> "Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the .add()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object
>   from the union of those elements and
>   the ones passed into the method." - http://api.jquery.com/add/

Your overlay is not a set of DOM elements yet. Can you just use append?:

```
overlay.append(popup).appendTo('body')
```

Answer (score 1):

But I've just found that removeing the id from the overlay fixes the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var popup = $('<div id="popup"><div class="popup-content"></div></div>');
        var popupContent = popup.children('div');
        var overlay = $('<div></div>');

        console.log(popup);
        console.log(popupContent);
        console.log(overlay);
        console.log(overlay.add(popup).appendTo('body'));
    });
```

I don't think it should be relevant whether the nodes are on the DOM or not yet as .add() is just combining two jQuery objects.

This is making no sense...

Comment: That is strange. If you pass an object to set the ID, it works. `var overlay = $('<div/>',{id:'overlay'});` Odd.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, surely the return value of $('<div id="overlay"></div>'), $('div', {id: 'overlay'}) and $('<div></div>') are the same... a jQuery object. (apart from the last one wouldn't have an ID attribute).

Comment: That is strange.  Maybe drop a post over on the jquery forums.  Sounds kinda bugish... :/

Comment: I've posted a simpler version on the jQuery forum: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-add-or-appendto-bug